# How to resolve Google Play Services library dependency with minimum required version

Tags: android, maven, google-play-services

I am trying to include a [SMS feature](https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/request) from Google play services support libraries to improve the authentication process. The documentation around it recommends using atleast minimum of 10.2 play services in order to use it.

> Prerequisites:
>   The SMS Retriever API is available only on Android devices with Play services version 10.2 and newer.

However, when I go to build my project specifying the 10.2.0 version of in gradle, Android studio tells me it is unable to resolve this dependency from either jcenter or google's repos.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:10.2.0'

Error:org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionNotFoundException: Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:10.2.0.
```

I tried searching for the package, but couldn't find that version: [google's maven](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/index.html) repos only show 11.0 and above.

It would be really helpful if someone could point me to the minimum available version of play services libraries over 10.2 that can be used to make this work.

Comment: PS: The feature works with 11.0.0 but I would rather be able to target users who are on slightly older play services version as well.

Answer (score 2):

Versions of Google Play services prior to `11.0.0` are only available through the [SDK Manager](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update.html#sdk-manager). Make sure you have installed the `Google Play services` item in the `SDK Tools` tab of the SDK Manager.

However, in the case of the `SmsReceiverClient` API, that class was only added in [Google Play services 11.0.0](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#june_2017_-_version_110) SDK. It may be that the underlying implementation *did* exist back to 10.2, but was not public.

In any case, Google Play services releases an SDK only after it is made available to all users and will automatically update the vast majority (99.5%+) of users within the first week or two of availability. Given that 11.0.0 has been available for over 6 months, it should not be any issue in relying on the 11.0.0 library.

Comment: I do have it installed (version 46) and it works for some of the other client libs. But this particular one: play-services-auth-api-phone does NOT seem to work for older numbers I tried. Is there a way to browse through the available versions for a specific package lib in this situation?  
 
The package numbers seem to be listed on google's docs, but only the latest ones: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Comment: They're all folders in your Android SDK, so it is easy to see which are available. I took another look through the release notes and it does look like 11.0.0 was the first version that this API was *publicly* available.

Comment: 11.0 being the earliest supported makes sense if looking through the maven repos: https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/index.html etc. But my concern is still why did Google choose to document the feature as being supported from play services 10.2 onwards as posted here: https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/request? I still feel, I am missing something to support users who have the play services apk between versions 10.2 and 11.0 on their devices, and unfortunately the folders in Android SDK only show the libs I already have downloaded which are 11.0 and 11.4 in this case.

Comment: Like I said in my answer, there should be ~no users left running Google Play services 10.0. Remember that there's two parts of Google Play services - the SDK you use and the app that runs on the phone. Just because it was only made public in 11.0 does not mean that it didn't exist on the app side since 10.2

Comment: I will accept the answer assuming this is what google wants. Unfortunately for me, within the test team itself we have several devices who refuse to upgrade apps (play services apk) automagically and have tagged the library as broken since it does not work for play services between 10.2 and 11.0 based on the requirements set by the feature documentation. The fact that google might not have data insight into these devices due to no or outdated services actually exacerbates the issue. In this case Google seems to be enforcing play services updates for a good user experience.

Comment: If a dev just reads the docs and validates that the user has play services greater than 10.2 using getPackageInfo, the validation will fail for supposedly supported users and fail at the point of attempting to talk to the APK binds hence ruining the user experience.

Comment: I don't know why you'd go through any of that. `SmsReceiverClient` already does everything it needs to for verification of Google Play services availability - just add your success and failure listeners as the guide says.

Comment: Because technically SmsRetrieverClient does not need to be instantiated until the SMS is about to be received. However, the SMS will be sent by a backend which needs to know whether to send the SMS (which costs money), based on the support for SMSRetriever on the device. The support can be checked by checking the packageInfo which I already have, or instantiating the SMSRetriever which seems redundant and doesn't respond with a specific version being supported or not. Either way, support seems to depend on the version of play services I set: 11.0 in this case like you had mentioned earlier.

Comment: The guide specifically mentions waiting until the receiver returns success before you send the SMS, probably for exactly the reason you mentioned (avoiding sending an SMS which you won't get a callback for).

Comment: It didn't feel like the docs specified the need of instantiation of client prior to sending the SMS though, the doc is confusing if that was the intention: 
// Get an instance of SmsRetrieverClient, *used to start listening for a matching*
// SMS message.
SmsRetrieverClient client = SmsRetriever.getClient(this /* context */);
 
I get the point though, and thanks for the explanation.

Comment: The 'After you have...started to listen for SMS messages' in the first line of [step 3](https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/request#3_send_the_phone_number_to_your_server) is the critical ordering line in the guide.

Comment: Sure. I get the underlying assumption in creating this feature, but as a developer for libraries, I cannot rely on those assumptions from Google. The ideal usage wouldn't necessarily make it easy to provide a good user experience for target markets where play services might not available. What would happen if the SMSRetrieverClient (or any other support lib feature) is imported on a device without play services from a manufacturer in China? The point is, play services features are not designed with that audience in mind, and its understandable. I can deal with this case based on the info.

Comment: You'll just get an `onFailure` callback. That's exactly what that callback is for - for making sure the API is available on the current device.

Comment: I have tried on a couple devices so far, but get a Fatal Exception when attempting to instantiate the client:
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Looper android.content.Context.getMainLooper()' on a null object reference 
at android.content.ContextWrapper.getMainLooper(ContextWrapper.java:101)
 at com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApi.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.phone.SmsRetrieverClient.<init>(Unknown)
 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzash.<init>(Unknown)
 at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.phone.SmsRetriever.getClient(Unknown Source)